# Insert data from database to several Excel files

Tags: sql, ssis, ssis-2012

I have several Excel destination files. So far I can load data from database into two files, on basis of two conditions:

1. LIKE of ‘ [0-9] %’
2. LIKE of ‘ % [A-Z]’

I use Conditional Split. Is it possible to somehow add another?

[image: SSIS exemple]

Comment: You can add further conditions to this split or you could add a multicast transformation if you need a number of conditional splits

Comment: Both of your conditions can evaluate to true at the same time - e.g `9test` so how do you want to deal with those cases?

Comment: I have revised your question to make it more readable.  However you need to provide more details of what you want to achieve (specific conditions) and how you want the process to flow.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you populate a condition-line in the Conditional Split properties, a new blank line will appear below the one you are editing.

You can use the new blank line to add another condition, and you can do this as many times as you want.   A conditional split is not limited to only two conditions/outputs.